# Clear SharedPreferences on a button's finish()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am just having a little problem on the clearing Sharing Preferences data.

```
    protected void onStop(){

    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SharedP", 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("inputValue", et1.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}


private void exitOptionsDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Exit")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setNegativeButton("No", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) { } })
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SharedP", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.clear();
                            editor.commit();
                            finish();
```

It is a exit button saying "Yes" this button will exit the app and also clear the data entered/saved before.

I test the app and I type the value in to the textview box, press home and then back to the app the value is there and is all good and working. So I go to my menu -> exit -> dialog pop up ask the user exit or not, and Yes, the app simply close it but however when I run the app again the value is still in the textview.

Not sure what I've done wrong :(

PS: I have just updated the editor.remove("SharedP"); with editor.clear(); and problem still remain.

Comment: If you want to clear the whole thing, use `editor.clear();`

Comment: thanks I have tried editor.clear(); as well but doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something here? You're setting a value in the `onStop()` method which is basically called after your `exitOptionsDialog()`, In other words, it doesn't matter if you call `editor.clear()` and `editor.commit()` in `exitOptionsDialog()` as the value is set in `onStop()`.

Comment: ah blaady hell, sorry for first ever app noob error :( got it working now. I have put the SharedPreferences codes in to public void onCreate, and now it works perfectly fine. How do I rep you and tick off this page for answered question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `editor.clear();` [SharedPreferences.Editor clear()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear%28%29)

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have tried it that and the value is still remain there when I re-run the app.